# std::hash specialisation for my own class and use it inside the class

Tags: c++, c++11

I define a class `Foo`, and would like to have a public member function that takes   `std::unordered_set<Foo>` as parameters type.

To be able to use `std::unordered_set<Foo>`, I have to specialize `std::hash<Foo>`  in namespace std.

That's ok if I do not try to use `std::unordered_set<Foo>` as paramter type in `Foo` member functions.

However, once I want to use `std::unordered_set<Foo>` as parameter type in `Foo` member functions, I Have a problem to define the specialization  `std::hash<Foo>`.
If I do it after the `Foo` declaration, there is an error on `Foo` declaration because `std::hash<Foo>` is not defined. It a move `std::hash<Foo>` definition before, it does not work either because now `Foo` is unknown. Forward declaration of `Foo`does not work in such situation.

Any ideas how to resolve this ?

Here is an example of such a class

```
class Foo
{
public:
  std::unordered_set<Foo>::iterator findClosest(std::unordered_set<Foo> const &others)
  {
    return std::end(others);
  }

  size_t hashValue() const {
    return std::hash<int>()(m_Member);
  }

private:
  int m_Member;
};

namespace std
{
  template <>
  struct hash<Foo>
  {
    size_t operator()(Foo const & bar) const
    {
      return bar.hashValue();
    }
  };
}
```

---

Using answers below, here is the code I finally use (I need to place some MY_EXPORT_MACRO because there is dlls):

In file Foo.h

```
class Foo;

namespace std
{
  template <>
  struct MY_EXPORT_MACRO hash<Foo>
  {
    size_t operator()(Foo const &bar) const;
  };
}

class MY_EXPORT_MACRO Foo
{
public:
  Foo const *findClosest(std::unordered_set<Foo> const &others);

  size_t hashValue() const
  {
    return std::hash<int>()(m_Member);
  }

  bool operator==(const platypus::Segment2D &other) const
  {
    return m_Member == other.m_Member;
  }

private:
  int m_Member;
};
```

In file Foo.cpp

```
size_t std::hash<Foo>::operator()(Foo const &bar) const
{
  return bar.hashValue();
}

Foo const *Foo::findClosest(std::unordered_set<Foo> const &others)
{
  Foo const *closest = nullptr;
  std::unordered_set<Foo>::const_iterator closestIt =
    std::min_element(std::begin(others), std::end(others), [this](Foo const &lhs, Foo const &rhs) {
      return std::abs(this->m_Member - lhs.m_Member) < std::abs(this->m_Member - rhs.m_Member);
    });

  if (closestIt != std::end(others))
  {
    closest = &(*closestIt);
  }

  return closest;
}
```

Comment: MSVC in VS 2015 does not implement two-phase lookup correctly, so certain templated things working (or not) when they don't (or do) in gcc/clang is basically coincidental. If you're writing new code, you should not rely on this, as it will eventually break.

Comment: Yes, I just tried in my real case, and it does no work. So I will fallback to the pointer version

Comment: Actually I am stuck because I cannot use to Pointer version neither, because it is not possible to get a `Foo*`  from a `std::unordered_set<Foo>::iterator`

Comment: What's wrong with `&*myIt` (aside from syntactic awkwardness)?

Comment: my bad, actually I have to return `Foo const *`and not a `Foo  *`, that's why I had problem with the Pointer version.

Answer (score 4):

The real problem in your example is that you want to use `std::unordered_set<Foo>::iterator` as return type. This requires that `unordered_set<Foo>` is fully instantiated, which requires `Foo` (and `std::hash<Foo>`) to be a complete class. But `Foo` is only a complete class at the end of its definition. Note that this problem does not exist with the by-reference function parameter, where the compiler does not have to fully instantiate the referenced class.

As originally suggested by **@MrTux**, you can fix everything else with forward declarations:

```
class Foo;

template<>
struct std::hash<Foo>;
```

If you return a `Foo*` instead, everything works:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/pJJcQY)

Whether that works for your design is another question.

---

I should note that you *can* have `std::hash<Foo>` be fully defined before `Foo`'s definition:

```
class Foo;

namespace std
{
  template <>
  struct hash<Foo>
  {
    size_t operator()(Foo const & bar) const;
  };
}

class Foo { /* ... */ };

size_t std::hash<Foo>::operator()(Foo const & bar) const
{
    return bar.hashValue();
}
```

That would allow you to return e.g. `std::unordered_set<Foo>` from methods in `Foo`, but it still does not fix the core issue of `Foo` being incomplete (and thus `std::unordered_set<Foo>::iterator` being unavailable) during its own definition.

Comment: Thank you, it effectively works with forward declaration if change the signature of `findClosest` to `Foo* findClosest(std::unordered_set<Foo> const &others)`.

So it is an interesting solution for me.

However if someone had a solution to be able to return an iterator (because it seems more clean for me), it would be perfect.

Comment: You can return an iterator by writing `auto findClosest(...) { return std::end(...); }` Like in [here](https://godbolt.org/z/WSm3Pk)

Comment: @Julian actually it does not work in my real case, because class Foo and its use are in different dlls, and I get an error "a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined". There is solutions for that but I do not want to deal with.

Comment: @Azias Well, in the background auto is somewhat like a template, the easiest solution would to just put the definition of findClosest in the header file. That way at the moment you include Foo, findClosest is defined.
That's why many, if not all, of the standard containers are simply put in header files.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you tagged the Question as C++11 (so we cannot rely on type deduction for the return type), so here is a solution that returns a `const_iterator` (`others` is const):

```
#include <unordered_set>

class Foo;

namespace std
{
  template <>
  struct hash<Foo>
  {
    size_t operator()(Foo const & bar) const;
  };
}

class Foo
{
public:
  template <class Hash>
  typename std::unordered_set<Foo, Hash>::const_iterator findClosest(std::unordered_set<Foo, Hash> const &others)
  {
    return std::end(others);
  }

  size_t hashValue() const {
    return std::hash<int>()(m_Member);
  }

private:
  int m_Member;
};

size_t std::hash<Foo>::operator()(Foo const & bar) const
{
    return bar.hashValue();
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::unordered_set<Foo> fs;
    f.findClosest(fs);
}
```

Comment: @Azias It actually makes no difference because both `iterator` and `const_iterator` are const iterators (and [may be the same type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/begin)) for `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`: ["Container elements may not be modified (even by non const iterators) since modification could change an element's hash and corrupt the container."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

Answer (score 2):

You might find the code is clearer and easier to maintain if you move the concerns of hashing Foo and finding closest distance into free functions.

Here's an example using `boost::hash` protocols (which I find to be very helpful)

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:

    // return a tuple of immutable values which should be hashed in order to
    // compute this object's hash value
    auto hashy_stuff() const // -> std::tuple<const int&> // if you are < c++14
    {
        return std::tie(m_Member);
    }

private:
  int m_Member;
};

// implement the boost::hash hash_value protocol in terms of hashy_stuff
// (we win because now it's DRY and works with all boost hash functions)
auto hash_value(Foo const& foo) -> std::size_t { return boost::hash_value(foo.hashy_stuff()); }

// implement std::hash in terms of boost::hash (again, DRY because it automatically
// uses hash_value())
namespace std { template<> struct hash<Foo> : ::boost::hash<Foo> {}; }

// implement findClosest as a free function. Its concerns are tangential to
// the Foo-ness of a Foo.
std::unordered_set<Foo>::const_iterator 
findClosest(Foo const& /*foo*/, std::unordered_set<Foo> const &others)
{
    // implementation here in terms of public interface
    return std::end(others);
}

extern auto make_foos() -> std::unordered_set<Foo>;
extern auto make_foo() -> Foo;

bool test()
{
    auto foos = make_foos();
    auto foo = make_foo();

    auto i = findClosest(foo, foos);

    return i != end(foos);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of specializing template in `std` namespace you can try below method if you like that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
struct FooHash;
class Foo {
    public:
    Foo(){
    }
    ~Foo(){
    }
    friend FooHash;
    private:
    std::string m_str;
};
struct FooHash
{
    std::size_t operator()(Foo const& f) const noexcept{
        return std::hash<std::string>{}(f.m_str);
    }
};
int main(){
    std::unordered_set<Foo,FooHash> fSet;
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f9cf337b62b650a)</kbd>

Comment: This completely ignores the core of the question: Using `std::unordered_set<Foo>` in the interface of `Foo`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Sorry My mistake